# Can I convert my oven to a four prong?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I live outside of Chicago, and my house has older wiring.  The wiring to the kitchen oven is armored cable with two hot conductors and a neutral.  My wiring system uses the metal sheathing of the AC as a grounding conductor.  I want to convert my current three prong plug to a four prong one.  Is it safe and within code to use the AC sheathing for a 60 amp circuit?  I thought I read somewhere that 20 amps is the limit.

My second question is: Is the grounding hole in in a 50 amp plug bonded to the surrounding metal plate like in a 15 amp plug? So, if the metal plate is connected to my metal box, which is grounded through the AC sheathing, I don't need a jumper cable from the back of the plug to the box, right?  The plug I bought is a Lengrand 3894CC6 and here's a couple of pics.  Thanks.

[image]  [image]

Comment: Is the box flush with the wall, or mounted so it sticks out from the wall?

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel I haven't installed it yet, but I was going to make it flush with the wall.

Comment: The armored cable's an existing run, correct?

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You'll need to use a 10AWG ground pigtail here

For a flush mounted box, NEC 250.146 and in particular 250.146(B) form the controlling Code on how to ground the device(s) inside:

> **250.146 Connecting Receptacle Grounding Terminal to Box.**
>   An equipment bonding jumper shall be used to connect the
>   grounding terminal of a grounding-type receptacle to a grounded box unless grounded as in 250.146(A) through (D). The
>   equipment bonding jumper shall be sized in accordance with
>   Table 250.122 based on the rating of the overcurrent device
>   protecting the circuit conductors.

.
.
.

> **(B) Contact Devices or Yokes.** Contact devices or yokes
>   designed and listed as self-grounding shall be permitted in
>   conjunction with the supporting screws to establish equipment
>   bonding between the device yoke and flush-type boxes.

Since your receptacle does *not* have a self-grounding clip on the mounting yoke (I know of no receptacles >20A that do, even), you will need to use a bare or green 10AWG copper wire from the receptacle ground terminal to a 10-32 screw in the designated grounding hole on the back of the box.  This will ground the yoke, faceplate, and receptacle grounding terminal, without relying on the receptacle mounting screws as a grounding path.

### As to that sheathing...

Since this is an *existing* run of cable, and the straight NEC does not limit the ampacity for which AC sheathing can be used as a ground path, I would use this sheathing as a ground, considering the obvious alternative (NEMA 10) is quite a bit worse here.  There is also the option of running a 10AWG bare copper wire back to the panel or grounding electrode conductor/system by any route possible to serve as a *retrofit* ground conductor as per NEC 250.130(C).

(The subpoints to NEC 250.118(8) you mention are Chicago-area specific amendments to the NEC.)

Comment: I think you forgot to answer the original question of whether using the cable sheath as a ground is acceptable, or if it needs to be a legacy NEMA 10.

Comment: Yes, I would indeed like to know if I can use the sheathing as a ground here. NEC 250.118(8)(a) says, "The circuit conductors contained in the tubing are protected by overcurrent devices rated at 20 amperes or less." My stove is on a 60 amp circuit. Maybe Chicago or more specifically Oak Park, IL has an exception?  Also, while reading this I noticed250.118(8)(b) says that the return path can't exceed 6 ft!?? Every run in my house is longer than 6 feet!  Maybe I'm reading it wrong.  Any input would help.

Comment: @user3080392 You say you are NOT in Chicago?  Chicago proper requires conduit. That 6' requirement doesn't apply to in-wall wiring, obviously as that would be unworkable.

Comment: @Harper Thanks for clearing that up.  No, I'm not in Chicago proper, rather, Oak Park. Good, the wiring I was referring to is in-wall.  I'm still unsure though if I should install a 4 prong or a 3 prong. My reading of the code makes it seem that I can't use the AC sheathing as a ground conductor if the circuit is over 20 amps.  Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: @user3080392 You want to use **4** prong. That way ground & neutral can be separated in the oven, which is safer than having them combined.

Comment: @user3080392 -- you would be reading it correctly for a new run of cable, but I'm considering it basically grandfathered since it already exists, and having ground and neutral separated is basically always better than having them combined